# Why won't my arraylist add more than one object?

Tags: java, arraylist

If you look at my if else block, you will see that I'm attempting to add a person object to my arraylist. However, it will only add/keep one object to the arraylist. If I loop through the array and print out all the elements, there will only be one person object, and it's always the last person instantiated. Does anyone know why this is happening? I've looked at similar posts already on Stack Overflow about this and couldn't find any help.

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {

  static ArrayList<Person> array = new ArrayList<Person>();

  Socket socket;

  public ClientThread(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      handleConnection(socket);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void handleConnection(Socket server) throws IOException {
    String x = "";
    //to get input from the client
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
    //Out to the client -- Enable auto-flush
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream())), true);
    //prints "got a connection from X" on server terminal
    System.out.println("got connection from " + server.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\n");

    while (true) {
      // get input from the client
      if((x = in.readLine()).length() != 0) {
        if (x.equals("END")) {
          System.out.println("This thread is shutting down. BYE!");
          break;
        } else if (x.equals("STORE") || x.equals("store")) {
          String storeName;
          System.out.println("Client wants to store someone's number.");
          out.println( "SERVER > Enter a name and number: ");
          storeName = in.readLine();
          array.add(new Person(storeName));
        } else {
          System.out.println("Echoing: " + x);
          out.println( "SERVER > ");
        }
      }
    }             
  }    
}
```

Here is my code for the class Person

```
class Person {

  protected String name;

  public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;       
  }

  //overide toString
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you *run* your server? Try using your debugger (or at least add some debugging statements to your server console). Also, `while(true)` should probably be `while ((x = in.readLine()).length() != 0)`

Comment: How do you print the `array`?

Comment: I'm running my server in the terminal. I did have some debugging statements( ex - a for loop running through the array and printing each element each time it was added) however I took them out to make this post not too convoluted.

Comment: for(int i =0; i < array.size(); i++)
  {
   System.out.println(array.get(i).toString());
  }

Comment: right above the array.add() line, put a System.out.println("HI"); statement and run it. Count the number of "HI"s and then you will know how manay times a new object is added to the list.